# Uncertainty of 自分 is is here

Tags: grammar

both the speaker and XXX are confident mysterious types, at the moment the reader isn't that informed about either character

XXX provokes MC to do something shocking,

> XXXの顔が、強ばった状態から、恐怖へと変わる。
>
> そこで初めて、自分の表情が『平時』ではない事に気付いた。

At this point who is 自分? is it obvious? At this point i thought it was referring to XXX noticing that she lost her composure for a moment. (this was indeed the first time the reader has seen this happen).

> MC「すまん、急だったから手加減が出来なかった」
>
> あまり恐がらせたくは無かった。
>
> 普通の学園生活を送れるかも知れない、そんなまやかしを、少しは信じていたかった。無理矢理、信じようとしていた。

reading a bit further I lean toward the MC constantly trying to put on a "『平時』" face to live out a normal life. And not putting on that sort of face made XXX scared.

in general, I feel that i have to work back to confirm if 自分 (and 自身/自ら as well) in a prior sentence was referring to who i initially thought it was more often that it should happen.

Is there a general rule of thumb to determine who 自分 is referring to without purely relying on context?

Answer (score 1):

It's protagonist's. You can interpret that the protagonist's facial expression made XXX frightened.

It it was XXX's, perspective would abruptly change, which is quite unnatural.